# Dynamically add item to ng-repeat array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, onsen-ui

I have to following array of items in angularjs

```
angular.module('app').controller('AppController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.items = {
        item1: {
            name: "Hamburger",
            complete: "50%",
            start: "2015/09/10 11:00",
            finish: "2015/09/11 04:00",
            work: "8 hours"
        },
        item2: {
            name: "Pasta",
            complete: "50%",
            start: "2015/09/10 11:00",
            finish: "2015/09/11 04:00",
            work: "8 hours"
        },
        item3: {
            name: "Potato",
            complete: "80%",
            start: "2015/09/10 18:00",
            finish: "2015/09/11 04:00",
            work: "8 hours"
        }
    };

    $scope.items.push({
        item4: {
            name: "Ham",
            complete: "50%"...
        }
    });
}
```

I want to add a new item to it, but it's not working.

I tried .push(item) method, but it fails with the following message in the console

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'push'
```

What's the easiest way to add an item to this existing array?

Comment: $scope.items = [ ] instead of $scope.items = {} should fix this

Comment: As @CodingEnthusiast has said using [] instead of {} for declaring $scope.items will work. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are using object (not an array)

Add value to object:
`$scope.items[key] = value;`

OR

Initialize array instead of object
`$scope.items = [....];`

Comment: Great answer, the key-value thing helped me understand it. I dynamically create the object from now on, and before adding the new objects, I initialize it with a simple $scope.items = {};

Answer (score 1):

Your **$scope.items** data **is not** an array, but an object. You declare it with `{ }`, and object does not get **.push()** method.

If you want to use the [**Array.prototype.push()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method, you have to delcare an **array**, so just change :

```
$scope.items = { ..... };
```

By

```
$scope.items = [ ..... ];
```

So you will be able to do :

```
$scope.items.push({item4 : { name: "Ham", complete: "50%"...}});
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code `$scope.items` is an object and not as array. So `$scope.items.push` will throw an error.

You can either convert `$scope.items` to an array or use the `$scope.items.item4 = { name: "Ham", complete: "50%"...};` to set the value.

Look at your data structure array makes more sense so that you can use the array methods.

```
angular.module('app').controller('AppController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
   $scope.items = [{
            name : "Hamburger",
            complete : "50%",
            start: "2015/09/10 11:00",
            finish: "2015/09/11 04:00",
            work: "8 hours"
        }, ...];

   $scope.items.push({ name: "Ham", complete: "50%"...});    
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Very good answer. I actually mixed up the array with the object, I'm very new to AngularJS (been using it for a couple of hours)

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in the code, it's a javascript Object not an array. Only Array supports pushing. Declare your array as below:

```
$scope.items = [
        item1 : {
            name : "Hamburger",
            complete : "50%",
            start: "2015/09/10 11:00",
            finish: "2015/09/11 04:00",
            work: "8 hours"
        },
        item2 : {
            name : "Pasta",
            complete : "50%",
            start: "2015/09/10 11:00",
            finish: "2015/09/11 04:00",
            work: "8 hours"
        },
        item3 : {
            name : "Potato",
            complete : "80%",
            start: "2015/09/10 18:00",
            finish: "2015/09/11 04:00",
            work: "8 hours"
        }
    ];
```

Now you can push new items and it will not throw the error.